# Memoryleak with NotifyIcon when setting icon property?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks

I am trying to set the icon of the notifyicon control but everytime i change the icon property i can see my memory for my application increase even though i release the icon.

This is my code (c#) :

```
public void CheckNotifyIcon(bool visible)
{

        if (notifyIcon.Icon != null)
            notifyIcon.Icon.Dispose();

            notifyIcon.Icon = visible 
                ? new Icon(Pic1, new Size(32, 32)) 
                : new Icon(Pic2, new Size(32, 32));
            notifyIcon.Visible = visible;

}
```

What have i done wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Do *not* use TaskMgr.exe or ProcExp.exe to draw any conclusions about memory usage, the statistics they show are far too crude and the .NET and Windows memory manager far too intricate.  If you suspect a leak then flush it out by running this code in a loop for a billion times or until you run out of patience, whichever comes first.

Comment: No leak here. You didn't say how you diagnosed a leak.

Comment: I just see the memory increase in taskmgr.exe and not getting released back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a single `NotifyIcon` and continually switching it's `Icon` property to temporary instances of `Icon`, I would create two `NotifyIcon` controls, and show/hide them appropriately. This way the `Icon` instances are created only once for the lifetime of the form, rather than continuously being disposed and re-created (and their eventual disposal is managed for you by the plumbing code which the WinForms designer writes for you). Whilst this won't tell you where the memory leak is occurring, it should avoid it in the first place.

Comment: Yes i thought of this solution but i am curious why i get memoryleak in the first place.

Comment: For the benefit of any future readers of this question, there is no memory leak in the code given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about firing up [Redgate's ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) to find out the cause?

In addition, I'd suggest to *not* catch and eat the exception to get more information.

Comment: The catch statement is for debugging puprose only, not live code. I could have shown u the same code without exception because it dont fail. I will however try redgate

Comment: how does an empty catch block aid debugging?

Comment: Ok, i removed the catch block, back to question please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no leak in the code you publish. You dispose of the icon and of course the .net garbage collector does not leak.

In a comment to the question you state:

> I just see the memory increase in taskmgr.exe and not
>   getting released back.

This is the source of your problem. Windows memory management is exceedingly complex, and task manager is not an appropriate tool to diagnose leaks.

Combine this with the .net garbage collector and the picture is even muddier. The garbage collector is perfectly at liberty to hold on to all allocated memory for as long as it can, so long as that does not impact on the rest of the system.

Detecting memory leaks in .net is a complex task and requires dedicated tools.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up for me. I went with the solution of having 2 notifyicons and switching between these but now i know that i cant trust taskmanager completely.

Comment: @syncis You can trust task manager. It is accurate. The difficulty is in how you interpret its output.